# Regex to find words starting with capital letters not at beginning of sentence

Tags: python, regex

I've managed to find the words beginning with capital Letters but can't figure out a regex to filter out the ones starting at the beginning of the sentence.

Each sentence ends with a full stop and a space.

- Test_string = `This is a Test sentence. The sentence is Supposed to Ignore the Words at the beginning of the Sentence.`
- Desired output = `['Test', 'Supposed', 'Ignore', 'Words', 'Sentence']`

I'm coding in Python.
Will be glad if someone can help me out with the regex :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. Your question got several downvotes because you did not show your efforts in solving the problem, and perhaps the desired output was not very clear. Consider this when asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following expression:

```
(?<!^)(?<!\. )[A-Z][a-z]+
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/slYWfj/2).

---

```
import re
mystr="This is a Test sentence. The sentence is Supposed to Ignore the Words at the beginning of the Sentence."

print(re.findall(r'(?<!^)(?<!\. )[A-Z][a-z]+',mystr))
```

Prints:

```
['Test', 'Supposed', 'Ignore', 'Words', 'Sentence']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has been messing with my head for a long time now.

Comment: Although if a capitalized word in the middle of a sentence begins on a new line (e.g. `"This is a\n" + "Test sentence."`), then the regex won't catch that word. I'm not sure if this will be an issue for the OP though.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic option. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/PHE7wW/2) for an explanation.

```
[^.]\s([A-Z]\w+)
```

---

```
import re
s = 'This is a Test sentence. The sentence is Supposed to Ignore the Words at the beginning of the Sentence, And others.'
re.findall(r'[^.]\s([A-Z]\w+)', s)
```

output

```
['Test', 'Supposed', 'Ignore', 'Words', 'Sentence', 'And']
```

Comment: What's the second `^` in the character set for?

Comment: That's not how it works. The metacharacter loses meaning in the character set.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are not correct. The first word "**This**" is missing.
Following code should word properly:

```
mystr="This is a Test sentence. The sentence is Supposed to Ignore
 the Words at the beginning of the Sentence."

print(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]{1,30}[^(A-Za-z)]',mystr))

output:

['This ', 'Test ', 'The ', 'Supposed ', 'Ignore ', 'Words ', 'Sentence.']
```